# How to get jenkins-cli work without granting any permissions to "anonymous"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am using **Jenkins version 2.89.2.** 
I have Role-based strategy enabled for authorization. Anonymous has not been granted any rights. I have some jobs being triggered remotely using the Jenkins cli. This used to work well when I was using an older version of Jenkins but once I moved to this version I am not able to get this working without granting Anonymous user build/job permissions.

In order to get this working without any permissions granted to Anonymous user, I tried to have a user whose ssh public key is updated in the Jenkins web ui (user configuration).
With this setup, when I try to use Jenkins-cli.jar as below, I get an error: **ERROR: No such job 'testing'**

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://<servername>:<port>/
         -i /user/jen/.ssh/id_rsa build "testing"
```

While searching around the internet, I saw that we can make this work by granting the "Anonymous user" read permission, I did that too but with that when I try to run the jerkins-cli jar (same command as above) I get the error: **ERROR: anonymous is missing the Job/Build permission**

I do not want to grant anonymous user Job/Build permissions.

Any ideas/thoughts to fix this please ?